# Alter table - existing column as primary key

Tags: mysql, primary-key, alter-table

I am attempting to set one of the columns in the table as primary key.

Here are the columns from the table:

[image]

Now, when I run the sql:

```
ALTER TABLE cb_company 
ADD PRIMARY KEY(uuid);
```

I get the following error -

```
Error Code: 1072. Key column 'uuid' doesn't exist in table
```

Here's the output of SHOW CREATE TABLE cb_company

```
CREATE TABLE `cb_company` ( `uuid` text,
                            `num_employees` text,
                            `name` text,
                            `aliases` text,
                            `short_description` text,
                            `primary_role` text,
                            `funding_total_usd` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
                            `num_investments` text,
                            `homepage` text,
                            `num_founders` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
                            `founders` text,
                            `num_investors` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  
                            `investors` text,
                            `location` text,
                            `category_list` text,  
                            `num_funding_rounds` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
                          ) ENGINE=InnoDB 
                            DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4  
                            COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Comment: Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE cb_company ;` and edit the questtion with the output

Comment: Added the output above.

Comment: Im guessing you need to *add* the column and *then* define it as the primary key.

Comment: 1) UUID() is the name of built-in function. So always wrap UUID field name with backticks; 2) TEXT datatype column cannot be used for index create without specifying the prefix keypart length.

Comment: PS. The best datatype for storing UUID values is `CHAR(36)`.

Comment: Better is to rearrange the bits and use `BINARY(16)`.  (This is discussed in a lot of other questions.)

Answer (score 1):

A `TEXT` column cannot be in an `INDEX` (a `PRIMARY KEY` is an index).  As Akina points out, uuids may as well be

```
uuid CHAR(36) CHARACTER SET ascii
```

Such is indexable.  Before changing away from `TEXT`, running your `ALTER` will give you

```
ERROR 1170 (42000): BLOB/TEXT column 'uuid' used in key specification without a key length
```

You could change the datatype, then do the `ALTER`.  Or if you are starting from scratch,

```
CREATE TABLE `cb_company` ( `uuid` CHARACTER SET ascii,
                        `num_employees` text,
                        ...
                        PRIMARY KEY(uuid)
                      ) ENGINE=InnoDB 
                        DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4  
                        COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

It is generally better to use `VARCHAR` with realistic limits.

If `num_employees` is a number, use `INT`.

If `announced_on` is a date, consider using `DATE` if you ever plan to compare or manipulate as a date.

Be aware that you will have to provide the `uuid` value.  One way is

```
INSERT INTO cb_company (uuid, num_employees, ... )
     VALUES
     (UUID(), ...)
```

Then a problem is -- how to retrieve the value given a company name?  Perhaps you also want some other index.

Etc.